# Recursive directory copy program

Tags: c#, performance, file-system

A little while ago, I had to write a little C# application to recover my HDD data (full context on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/939536/windows-cant-copy-a-file-that-i-can-read-manually/940151))

To answer my problem I developed a console application which job was to recursively copy the entire folder tree of my HDD.

The code can be seen below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CopyCat
{
    class Program
    {
        private static long _fileCount = 0;
        private static long _byteCount = 0;
        private static long _byteProgress = 0;
        private static ProgressBar _progressCount = new ProgressBar();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Directory.Exists(args[0]);
            Directory.Exists(args[1]);

            FileDiscovery(args[0]);
            FileCopy(args[0], args[1]);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void FileCopy(String source, String dest)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(source, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (file == null) continue;

                        var oFile = File.OpenRead(file);
                        var dFile = File.Open(Path.Combine(dest, Path.GetFileName(file)), FileMode.Create,
                            FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                        oFile.CopyTo(dFile, 104857600);

                        oFile.Close();

                        dFile.Flush();
                        dFile.Close();

                        _byteProgress += new FileInfo(file).Length;

                        _progressCount.Report((double)_byteProgress / (double)_byteCount);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[COPY][ERROR] : Couldn't copy file  : {0} => {1}", file, e.Message);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(source, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                {
                    if (directory == @"G:\$RECYCLE.BIN") continue;
                    var dir = Path.GetFileName(directory);
                    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(dest, dir)))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(dest, dir));
                    }

                    FileCopy(directory, Path.Combine(dest, dir));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[COPY][WARNING] : Couldn't open directory  : {0}", source);
            }
        }

        static void FileDiscovery(String dir)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                {
                    _fileCount++;
                    _byteCount += new FileInfo(file).Length;
                }
                foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                {
                    FileDiscovery(directory);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[DISCOVERY][WARNING] : Couldn't open directory : {0}", dir);
            }
        }

        static String HumanReadableByteCount(long bytes, Boolean si = false, int precision = 2)
        {
            int unit = si ? 1000 : 1024;
            if (bytes < unit) return bytes + " B";
            int exp = (int)(Math.Log(bytes) / Math.Log(unit));
            String pre = (si ? "kMGTPE" : "KMGTPE")[(exp - 1)] + (si ? "" : "i");
            return String.Format("{0} {1}{2}", Math.Round(bytes / Math.Pow(unit, exp), precision), pre, si ? "b" : "B");
        }
    }
}
```

(Using a custom [ProgressBar](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/DanielSWolf/0ab6a96899cc5377bf54/raw/c8a9bc27d7fc4375ea4eba645ad42735fbc299b9/ProgressBar.cs))

I wanted to know specifically how I could improve the copying speed.

Comment: The latest version of the code will be available here : https://gist.github.com/sidewinder94/d15c9aab985e12d747fc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
Directory.Exists(args[0]);
Directory.Exists(args[1]);
```

doesn't serve any purpose because you aren't evaluating the returned boolean value. In fact its more dangerous to use it with the `args` not checked for `null` at all. Your application will just crash if the application is called using only one or no argument at all.

---

The `static void FileDiscovery()` method would benefit from a better name like `CalculateDirectorySize()` and by returning a `long` instead of `void`.

Another point to mention is that the [`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class contains the method [`GetFileSystemInfos()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383457(v=vs.110).aspx) which would lead to the following change

```
    private static long CalculateDirectorySize(String dir)
    {
        long directorySize = 0;
        var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
        try
        {
            foreach (var fileInfo in dirInfo.GetFileSystemInfos("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                directorySize += fileInfo.Length;
            }

            foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
               directorySize += CalculateDirectorySize(directory);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[DISCOVERY][WARNING] : Couldn't open directory : {0}", dir);
        }
        return directorySize;
    }
```

I have added `private` access modifier to the method, because it is a good habit to add one.

Because `_fileCount` is no where used I have removed it.

---

The `FileCopy()` method is using a strange way to copy the files by reading and writing them using `FileStream`'s.

- A more idiomatic way would be to use one of the overloaded [`File.Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods. This methods are doing under the hood the same like your code but the streams are properly closed if any exception occurs.
- `Directory.CreateDirectory()` can be called regardless if the directory exists or not. You can just skip the check for `Exists()`.
- Having three times `Path.Combine(dest, dir)` won't be necessary if the result is stored in a variable.
- Instead of calling `GetFileName()` for a directory you should call `GetDirectoryName()`

this would result in the following change

```
    private static void FileCopy(String source, String dest)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(source, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(dest, Path.GetFileName(file)));

                    _byteProgress += new FileInfo(file).Length;

                    _progressCount.Report((double)_byteProgress / (double)_byteCount);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[COPY][ERROR] : Couldn't copy file  : {0} => {1}", file, e.Message);
                }
            }
            foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(source, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                if (directory == @"G:\$RECYCLE.BIN") continue;

                var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(directory);
                var destination = Path.Combine(dest, dir)

                Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);

                FileCopy(directory, destination);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[COPY][WARNING] : Couldn't open directory  : {0}", source);
        }
    }
```

Based on the comment

> I was aware of the `File.Copy()` method at the time of writing the application BUT (and that's why I included the context) this method was throwing the same error as my explorer when used : that the file was not accessible and/or corrupted.

I would like to suggest to only use this kind of copy operation if the `File.Copy()` method throws an `IOException` having its own method like so

```
private static readonly int blockSize = 104857600;  
private static bool SafeFileCopy(string source, string destination) {

    try
    {
        using(var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(source))
        using(var destinationStream = File.Open(destination, FileMode.Create,
                            FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            sourceStream.CopyTo(destinationStream, blockSize);
            return true
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do some logging
    }
    return false; 

}
```

Resulting in the former `foreach` like so

```
           foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(source, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                string destinationFile = Path.Combine(dest, Path.GetFileName(file));
                try
                {
                    File.Copy(file, destinationFile);

                    _byteProgress += new FileInfo(file).Length;

                    _progressCount.Report((double)_byteProgress / (double)_byteCount);
                }
                catch (IOException ioex)
                {
                    if (!SafeFileCopy(file, destinationFile))
                    {
                         // do some logging here
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[COPY][ERROR] : Couldn't copy file  : {0} => {1}", file, e.Message);
                }
            }
```

Basically you should only catch exceptions which you can handle **or** which you only need to log/swallow. **But** you should always catch specific exceptions only. Catching `Exception` itself is a bad habit so for the `SafeFileCopy()` this would be for you to change.

Comment: I was aware of the `File.Copy()` method at the time of writing the application BUT (and that's why I included the context) this method was throwing the same error as my explorer when used : that the file was not accessible and/or corrupted. Which was not the case when manually copying using streams. And since the performance was less than good, I came to post the question :)

Comment: Thanks for the rest of your remarks, I will be applying them.

Comment: Would you know of any way to speed up the copy between the streams ? Or is it a question better asked on SO ?

Comment: Basically you have used a high blocksize and I guess that the bottleneck is your harddisc. You can ask on SO or better search first on SO.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/32237548/2655508

Comment: Ok, I supposed as much, the source disk was in a pretty bad shape when I copied the data from it, I was lucky to get them all out of it before it stopped.

Comment: Just for reference, seems that an optimal choice for the blocksize is ~4kb : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033771/file-i-o-with-streams-best-memory-buffer-size

Answer (score 0):

Use File.Copy. They use some lower level libraries that are much faster than copying streams. This improved performance for our application quite a bit.

Here's the code that File.Copy uses to actually copy the file (notice Win32Native.CopyFile):

```
/// <devdoc> 
///    Note: This returns the fully qualified name of the destination file.
/// </devdoc>
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Machine)]
[ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine)]
internal static String InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, bool overwrite)
{
    Contract.Requires(sourceFileName != null);
    Contract.Requires(destFileName != null);
    Contract.Requires(sourceFileName.Length > 0);
    Contract.Requires(destFileName.Length > 0);

    String fullSourceFileName = Path.GetFullPathInternal(sourceFileName);
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, new String[] { fullSourceFileName }, false, false).Demand();
    String fullDestFileName = Path.GetFullPathInternal(destFileName);
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, new String[] { fullDestFileName }, false, false).Demand();

    bool r = Win32Native.CopyFile(fullSourceFileName, fullDestFileName, !overwrite);
    if (!r)
    {
        // Save Win32 error because subsequent checks will overwrite this HRESULT.
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        String fileName = destFileName;

        if (errorCode != Win32Native.ERROR_FILE_EXISTS)
        {
            // For a number of error codes (sharing violation, path 
            // not found, etc) we don't know if the problem was with 
            // the source or dest file.  Try reading the source file.
            using (SafeFileHandle handle = Win32Native.UnsafeCreateFile(fullSourceFileName, FileStream.GENERIC_READ, FileShare.Read, null, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                if (handle.IsInvalid)
                    fileName = sourceFileName;
            }

            if (errorCode == Win32Native.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
            {
                if (Directory.InternalExists(fullDestFileName))
                    throw new IOException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_FileIsDirectory_Name", destFileName), Win32Native.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, fullDestFileName);
            }
        }

        __Error.WinIOError(errorCode, fileName);
    }

    return fullDestFileName;
}
```

Comment: If they're using `File.Copy`, then why do you need to show the code for it?  It would be customary to show how the code is different if you use `File.Copy`, not how `File.Copy` itself works.